# Add custom scripts for RPM package for a Play scala project

Tags: scala, rpm, rpmbuild, playframework-2.4, sbt-native-packager

I would like to add a few commands to the RPM package (built using sbt-native-packager) for a Play scala project. For example:

```
mkdir -p /opt/myapp
chmod +w /opt/myapp
```

so that they can be executed when installing the RPM package via yum.

I saw in a standard sbt project, looks like we could use custom template:

```
src/templates/start
```

but in a Play project, we have the following folders:

```
app
conf
project
dist
```

where we don't have `src` folder at all.

I would like to know how to add custom commands which can be run before or after installing RPM for a Play project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used this functionality of the sbt-native-packager, but I do know that RPM spec files support defining scripts that run in specific events (e.g. %pre - runs just before install).

It looks like sbt-native-package supports this by overriding the `maintainerScripts`:

```
// overriding
import RpmConstants._
maintainerScripts in Rpm := Map(
  Pre -> Seq("""echo "pre-install""""),
  Post -> Seq("""echo "post-install""""),
  Pretrans -> Seq("""echo "pretrans""""),
  Posttrans -> Seq("""echo "posttrans""""),
  Preun -> Seq("""echo "pre-uninstall""""),
  Postun -> Seq("""echo "post-uninstall"""")
)
```

**Please note this is only available from 1.1.0+ of sbt-native-package.**

There are a couple of other approaches which are detailed in the [documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/rpm.html#scriptlet-changes)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I saw that in document, but couldn't get it work.

It cannot find the import, which is very strange:

    build.sbt:1: error: not found: object RpmConstants
    import RpmConstants._
       ^

I've already configured the plugin in project/plugins.sbt

    addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.0.6")

Comment: This example is from me new 1.1.x releases ( at the moment in RC phase )